# How to access a table item in Sharepiont web database (Access 2010) by url?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, ms-access-2010

I have a Sharepoint web database published in Sharepoint.  I would like to email my colleague a URL of a particular table item.  Is there any way to construct a url query string for that?  I understand it isn't supported by default.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  The url of Access Web follows a convention:

Default.aspx#Type=[Form or Report]&Name=[form name]&Where=[Condition to filter]

**Please note the condition clause needs to be "=ID=1" and encoded

Hope it can be helpful to those that want to customize access web apps.